# Counting values in a DataFrame based on a condition -- too slow

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas

Given a pandas DF that looks like this:

```
   key  value
0    0      A
1    0      A
2    1      A
3    1      B
4    2      C
5    2      B
6    2      B
```

I'm trying to obtain the counts of each of the values for each of the keys, that is this:

```
   key      A    B    C
0    0      2    0    0
1    1      1    1    0
2    2      0    2    1
```

I'm using this code, which proves to be too slow for my needs (the actual data is about 20,000 keys, 200 unique values, and about 100 values per key). Why is it slow, and what can I do to make it faster?

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import random

n_keys = 200
values_per_key = 200
n_unique_values = 200
total_rows = n_keys * values_per_key

keys = [i//values_per_key for i in range(total_rows)]
values = [random.randint(0, n_unique_values-1) for i in range(total_rows)]
data = {'key': keys, 'value': values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#df = pd.DataFrame({'key': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
# 'value': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B']})

counts = defaultdict(list)
values = df['value'].value_counts().index
keys = sorted(df['key'].value_counts().index)

for key in keys:
    for value in values:
        # the following line makes this super slow
        ind = (df['key'] == key) & (df['value'] == value)
        counts[value].append(ind.sum())

print(pd.DataFrame(counts, index=keys))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['key'], df['value']).reset_index()
df.columns.name=None

print df
   key  A  B  C
0    0  2  0  0
1    1  1  1  0
2    2  0  2  1
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Just for my learning though, if I did want to achieve this using a loop instead of using `crosstab` (I know there's no reason to), can my approach be made much faster?

Comment: Hard question for me. Maybe. But in pandas solutions is the best trying to avoid for loops.